# npm ERR! when installing Firebase Tools (errno -17, EEXIST: file already exists, symlink)

Tags: javascript, firebase, macos, firebase-tools

I'm installing Firebase Tools for a new project on my new Macbook Air M1 and am running into the following issue on running the command `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/bin/firebase
npm ERR! errno -17
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, symlink '../lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js' -> '/usr/local/bin/firebase'
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/firebase
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
```

I have googled a lot and have no leads...

Also tried `npm clean cache`, `npm clean cache --force` and npm install with --force as recommended by the error message:

`npm install -g --force firebase-tools`

```
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/firebase
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/firebase: node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local/bin
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/firebase
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.
```

Update: I've finally figured out how to find hidden files on a mac and deleted the offending file. I now get this error:

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
/usr/local/bin/firebase -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js

> re2@1.16.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/re2
> install-from-cache --artifact build/Release/re2.node --host-var RE2_DOWNLOAD_MIRROR || npm run rebuild

Trying https://github.com/uhop/node-re2/releases/download/1.16.0/darwin-x64-83.br ...
Writing to build/Release/re2.node ...
Trying https://github.com/uhop/node-re2/releases/download/1.16.0/darwin-x64-83.gz ...
Writing to build/Release/re2.node ...
Building locally ...

> re2@1.16.0 rebuild /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/re2
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN EACCES current user ("nobody") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/macshac/Library/Caches/node-gyp/14.17.1"
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/re2/.node-gyp"
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/re2/.node-gyp'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/re2
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! re2@1.16.0 rebuild: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the re2@1.16.0 rebuild script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
(node:11071) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 1
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11071) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11071) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

> protobufjs@6.11.2 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/protobufjs
> node scripts/postinstall

+ firebase-tools@9.16.0
added 694 packages from 431 contributors in 32.015s
```

(It also doesn't work without `sudo`)

Comment: Seems like this question has been asked before [Several Times](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/29430002) and it appears it's just a warning. Do any of those posts help?

Comment: Would love if you found a solution for me, please link to it! I see similar questions but none with same errorno -17 or any helpful solutions...

Answer (score 2):

Run the command with sudo: Try running the command again with 'sudo' in front of it, like this: sudo npm install -g firebase-tools. This will run the command with administrator privileges, which should give it the necessary permissions to create the directory.

Comment: Hi, original question already mentions the use of `sudo`. Therefore, this not addresses the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to delete the offending existing file (firebase.js) by using `Command + Shift + G` to search the hidden file path `/usr/local/bin`
I then got the second set of errors shown in the question update. I realized at this point I was in a directory where I already had a firebase project and changed directory to the new project and ran `sudo npm install -g firebase-tools` again and it worked.

I'm still a little confused, but ultimately I think what did it was deleting the offending file. Though I'm still not sure why the directory I was in mattered as it was a global install...

Answer (score 1):

I solved it just by using `--force` to overwrite existing files with `sudo`.

```
sudo npm install -g firebase-tools --force
```

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory. In this example, you will create and use hidden directory in your home directory.

1-Back up your computer.

2-On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

mkdir ~/.npm-global

3-Configure npm to use the new directory path:

npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'

4-In your preferred text editor, open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH

5-On the command line, update your system variables:

source ~/.profile

6-To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

npm install -g jshint
Instead of steps 2-4, you can use the corresponding ENV variable (e.g. if you don't want to modify ~/.profile):

NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=~/.npm-global

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled homebrew and it seemed to fix the issue.

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

then ran `npm audit fix`

Comment: Also, used 'npm cache clean' but ----> npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues

Comment: run 'npm cache verify' for peace of mind after if you want